# Obtain a Neyman-Pearson Test of H0: p1=p2=2/5 against the alternative p1=1/2 and p2=1/5 when the type 1 error is 0.05

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, neyman-pearson-lemma

I kinda have some trouble trying to start with this question.

[image: a busy cat]

I  know how to derive a Neyman-Pearson Test and its critical region. My main concern is deriving the Likelihood function of the sample given its null hypothesis and its alternative hypothesis.

I'd like to solve this on my own but I'm not sure how to start it.

Comment: If $\boldsymbol N$ is a vector-valued random variable for the outcomes of $100$ trials, the relevant distribution of $N$ is multinomial with $n = 100$ and $k = 3$ possible outcomes per trial, with probabilities of outcome $j$ equal to $p_j$, so $N_1 + N_2 + N_3 = 100$ and the PMF is $$\Pr[\boldsymbol N = (N_1, N_2, N_3)] = \frac{100!}{N_1! \, N_2! \, N_3!} p_1^{N_1} p_2^{N_2} p_3^{N_3}.$$  Under the null hypothesis, what is the probability of observing $\boldsymbol N = (N_1, N_2, N_3)$?  Under the alternative, what is $\Pr[\boldsymbol N = (N_1, N_2, N_3)]$?

Comment: I think this may help. However, I'm a bit unsure about the PMF. What  are we finding with Pr(N=(N1,N2,N3))? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: The multinomial distribution is a discrete probability distribution on a *vector-valued* random variable.  If I throw such a die 4 times, then I could for example observe an outcome of ${\boldsymbol N} = (2,1,1)$, which represents rolling 2 ones, 1 two, and 1 three.

Comment: Oh now I feel silly, thanks for the help. I think I managed to find the rejection region but I'm not sure if I did it right though.

Comment: One last thing. Is it right to say that N1 is a binomial distribution of (100,p1) ?

Comment: $N_1$ as described in the question is not a random variable.  It's a fixed but unspecified value.  If you mean "what is the distribution of the number of ones obtained in 100 trials," then yes, that is binomial with $n = 100$ and probability of 'success' equal to $p = p_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I think I managed to solve it somehow.